# javascript callback returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I need to call the function from command prompt which is available inside js. Here i am calling the method as `node test.js callfunction` from command promt. But it's returning `undefined`. Here is my code,

```
module.exports = {
    callfunction: function (param) {
        function1(param, function (error, result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
};    
var function1 = function (param, callback) {
    callback(null, true);
};    
require('make-runnable/custom')({
    printOutputFrame: false
});
```

Here is the output of the above code

```
true
undefined
```

How can i fix this issue? please someone advice me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, it prints value "true" as expected. Javascript function allways returns "undefined" in case if return statement is not defined.

Sample with return statement:

```
module.exports = {
    callfunction: function (param) {
        return function1(param, function (error, result) {
            return result;
        });
    }
};    
var function1 = function (param, callback) {
    return callback(null, true);
};

module.exports.callfunction(123);
```

Comment: Inside the `function1()` i have other logic's like database connection and loops are there. I have added `return callback()` inside these logics. Ex. `var function1 = function (param, callback) mongoose.connection.close(function () {return callback(null, true);             );};` In this case first it returns `undefined`. how can i resolve this scenario

Comment: Are you using some API or is it your custom function "mongoose.connection.close()"? If it is your code, check answer I posted recently to use jquery Deffered function or pure JavaScript callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, there is nice function for dealing with asynchronous tasks, it is called [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
function doAsyncTask() {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    $.get(url, params, function(data) {
        //process data
        d.resolve();
    }).fail(function(e) {
        console.error("get request failed", e);
        d.reject();
    });

    return d;
}

function onAsyncTaskFinished() {
    console.log("async task is finished");
}

function onAsyncTaskFail() {
    console.error("async task is failed");
}

doAsyncTask().then(onAsyncTaskFinished, onAsyncTaskFail);
```

In pure JavaScript you can pass callback function and call it after asynchronous task is finished.

```
function doAsyncTask(callbackFn) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callbackFn();
    },1000);
}

function onAsyncTaskFinished() {
    console.log("async task is finished");
}

doAsyncTask(onAsyncTaskFinished);
```